# Center Logo and nav bar horizontal

Tags: html, image, css, center, nav

How can i center my logo (img) and menu links horizontal. I want the logo to be at the left and menu at right but horizontal centered.
here's my code!

thanks

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src=https://app.box.com/representation/file_version_186133299510/image_2048/1.png class="logo"></a>
  </div>
    <nav class="menu">
                <a href="#">Branding</a>
                                <a href="#">Logos</a>
                                <a href="#">Illustration</a>
                                <a href="#">Web</a>
                                <a href="#">Poster</a>
                                <a href="#">Letters</a>
                                <a href="#">All</a>
                                <a href="#">About</a>
     </nav>

</div>
<div class="main-intro">
       <h2>Let's create something great together!</h2>
    </div>
```

---CSS---

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu-container{
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 30px;
  position


}

.logo {
  height: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}


.menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 2em; 2em; 0; 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Randomood/pen/KmJpWX?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

try removing the height of your logo from you css?

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

**EDITED:**

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu-container{
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}

.logo {
  height:10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 4.5em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: mm that doesn't fix it, only makes the logo bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just try doing this to your "menu-container"

```
.menu-container{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
   justify-content:center;
   background-color: gray;
   margin: 30px;
 }
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwedep?editors=1100)